# Stripe. Transfer money from two stripe balances to one Connected account

Tags: stripe-payments

We need a possibility to have two balances on our stripe platform: first for our platform commission (balance1) and second for saving vauchers money (balance2).
Is it possible to make a transfers from this both balances to on connected account?

Comment: You can use the Stripe Application Fee Option: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges

Answer (score 0):

This is something you would keep track off on your end. Stripe would aggregate the balance in that case and just give you a number for the amount available and a number for the amount pending. You can not have split balances specific to your business.

I would recommend reaching out to Stripe to discuss your business model and what you are trying to achieve though since it's not specifically about code or Stripe's API.